How to Adjust Open Position Size via Binance API Without Closing Position (Using Python)?
I'm currently working on integrating Binance API into our trading bots using Python and need some help with managing open positions. Specifically, I'm looking to understand how to increase or decrease the amount of an open position (either long or short, in futures or spot) without having to close and reopen the position.
Is there a way to adjust the position size dynamically via the Binance API? Any guidance or references to the relevant API endpoints would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I have been experimenting with the Binance API using Python. Specifically, I have tried using the POST /fapi/v1/positionSide/dual endpoint for futures and POST /api/v3/order endpoint for spot trading to manage open positions. However, these approaches seem to require closing the current position and opening a new one to adjust the position size.
I was expecting to find a way to dynamically adjust the size of an open position without having to close and reopen it, allowing for more flexible and efficient trading strategies. Any insights or examples on how to achieve this using the Binance API would be highly beneficial.
